# Remove string after last hyphen

Tags: php, regex, string

I would like to remove the last hyphen and anything after it in a string. After looking I found something that does the first hyphen but not last:

```
$str = 'sdfsdf-sdfsdf-abcde';
$str = array_shift(explode('-', $str));
```

Current String

```
$str = 'sdfsdf-sdfsdf-abcde';
```

Desired Result

```
$str = 'sdfsdf-sdfsdf';
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this `preg_replace`:

```
$repl = preg_replace('/-[^-]*$/', '', $str);
//=> sdfsdf-sdfsdf
```

`-[^-]*$` will match `-` followed by 0 or more non-hyphen characters before end of line.

Comment: With `implode/explode` you can use: `$repl = implode('-', array_slice(explode('-', $str), -2));`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`strrpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) to get the last index, and then use [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to get the desired result.

```
$str = 'sdfsdf-sdfsdf-abcde';
$pos = strrpos($str , "-");
if ($pos !== false) {
   echo substr($str, 0, $pos);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close. Just use `array_pop()` instead of `array_shift()`. `array_pop()` removes last element of array. You need, of course, use `implode()` later to put the strign together again.

```
$arr = explode('-', $str);
array_pop($arr);
$str = implode('-', $arr);
```

It's important not to do that in one line since `array_pop()` works on a reference to the array and it modfies it, and then returns only removed element.

There are a few other possible solutions mentions by other answers.

Comment: Yeah, I've made a mistake. `array_pop` returns removed element ;-) Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bulky but it will work for you:

```
$str = 'sdfsdf-sdfsdf-abcde';
$pieces = explode("-",$str);
$count = count($pieces);

for ($x = 0; $x <= $count - 2; $x++) {
   $desired_result .= $pieces[$x].'-';
} 
$desired_result = substr($desired_result, 0, -1);

echo $desired_result;
```

if you have a lot of them you can use this function:

```
function removeLast($str){
    $pieces = explode("-",$str);
    $count = count($pieces);

    for ($x = 0; $x <= $count - 2; $x++) {
       $desired_result .= $pieces[$x].'-';
    } 
    $desired_result = substr($desired_result, 0, -1);

    return $desired_result;
}
```

you call it by:

```
$str = 'sdfsdf-sdfsdf-abcde';
$my_result = removeLast($str);
```